# How can get null column after UNPIVOT?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have got the following query:

```
WITH data AS( 
    SELECT * FROM partstat WHERE id=4
)
SELECT id, AVG(Value) AS Average
FROM (
    SELECT id, 
    AVG(column_1) as column_1, 
    AVG(column_2) as column_2, 
    AVG(column_3) as column_3 
    FROM data
    GROUP BY id
) as pvt
UNPIVOT (Value FOR V IN (column_1,column_2,column_3)) AS u
GROUP BY id
```

if `column_1`,`column_2` and `column_3` (or one of this columns) have  values then i get result as the following:

> id,   Average
>
> 4, 5.12631578947368

if `column_1`,`column_2` and `column_3` have `NULL` values then the query does not return  any rows as the following:

> id,   Average

my question is how can i get as the following result if columns contents `NULL` values?

> id,   Average
>
> 4, NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using COALESCE or ISNULL?

e.g.

```
ISNULL(AVG(column_1), 0) as column_1,
```

This does mean that you will get 0 as the result instead of 'NULL' though - do you **need** null when they are all NULL?

Edit:

Also, is there any need for an unpivot? Since you are specifying all 3 columns, why not just do:

```
SELECT BankID, (column_1 + column_2 + column_3) / 3 FROM partstat
WHERE bankid = 4
```

This gives you the same results but with the NULL

Of course this is assuming you have 1 row per bankid

Edit:

UNPIVOT isn't supposed to be used like this as far as I can see - I'd unpivot first then try the AVG... let me have a go...

Edit:

Ah I take that back, it is just a problem with NULLs - other posts suggest ISNULL or COALESCE to eliminate the nulls, you could use a placeholder value like -1 which could work e.g.

```
SELECT bankid, AVG(CASE WHEN value = -1 THEN NULL ELSE value END) AS Average 
FROM ( 
    SELECT bankid,  
    isnull(AVG(column_1), -1) as column_1 ,
    AVG(Column_2) as column_2 ,
    Avg(column_3) as column_3 
    FROM data     
    group by bankid
) as pvt 
UNPIVOT (Value FOR o in (column_1, column_2, column_3)) as u
GROUP BY bankid
```

You need to ensure this will work though as if you have a value in column2/3 then column_1 will no longer = -1. It might be worth doing a case to see if they are all NULL in which case replacing the 1st null with -1

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example without UNPIVOT:

```
DECLARE @partstat TABLE (id INT, column_1 DECIMAL(18, 2), column_2 DECIMAL(18, 2), column_3 DECIMAL(18, 2))
INSERT @partstat VALUES 
(5, 12.3, 1, 2)
,(5, 2, 5, 5)
,(5, 2, 2, 2)
,(4, 2, 2, 2)
,(4, 4, 4, 4)
,(4, 21, NULL, NULL)
,(6, 1, NULL, NULL)
,(6, 1, NULL, NULL)
,(7, NULL, NULL, NULL)
,(7, NULL, NULL, NULL)
,(7, NULL, NULL, NULL)
,(7, NULL, NULL, NULL)
,(7, NULL, NULL, NULL)


;WITH data AS( 
    SELECT * FROM @partstat
)
SELECT  

        pvt.id,
        (ISNULL(pvt.column_1, 0) + ISNULL(pvt.column_2, 0) + ISNULL(pvt.column_3, 0))/ 
        NULLIF(
            CASE WHEN pvt.column_1 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
            CASE WHEN pvt.column_2 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
            CASE WHEN pvt.column_3 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
        , 0)
        AS Average
FROM (
    SELECT id, 
    AVG(column_1) as column_1, 
    AVG(column_2) as column_2, 
    AVG(column_3) as column_3 
    FROM data
    GROUP BY id
) as pvt
```